How to validate and handle edge cases in a coast fire calculator?
I’m building a web application to calculate the Coast FIRE (Financial Independence, Retire Early) number. The calculator estimates the future value of current savings using compound interest, assuming no additional contributions.
The formula I’m using is:
Future Value = Present Value × (1 + Rate of Return) ^ Years
I’ve implemented the following JavaScript function for this calculation:
function calculateFutureValue(presentValue, rateOfReturn, years) {
    return presentValue * Math.pow(1 + rateOfReturn, years);
}

// Example usage
const presentValue = 50000; // $50,000
const rateOfReturn = 0.07;  // 7%
const years = 30;           // 30 years

const futureValue = calculateFutureValue(presentValue, rateOfReturn, years);
console.log(futureValue);   // Expected output: ~380612.54

The code works correctly for basic inputs, but I want to handle edge cases to make it more robust. For example:

Invalid inputs: What’s the best way to validate that presentValue, rateOfReturn, and years are non-negative numbers?
Edge cases: How should I handle scenarios where one or more inputs are missing, null, or undefined?

I gather user input using basic HTML form fields, as shown below:
<form id="fire-calculator">
    <label for="presentValue">Present Value ($):</label>
    <input type="number" id="presentValue" min="0" required>

    <label for="rateOfReturn">Rate of Return (%):</label>
    <input type="number" id="rateOfReturn" min="0" step="0.01" required>

    <label for="years">Years:</label>
    <input type="number" id="years" min="0" required>

    <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>

Here’s the JavaScript I’ve written to gather the form inputs and call the calculation function:
document.getElementById("fire-calculator").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const presentValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("presentValue").value);
    const rateOfReturn = parseFloat(document.getElementById("rateOfReturn").value) / 100;
    const years = parseInt(document.getElementById("years").value, 10);

    try {
        if (isNaN(presentValue) || isNaN(rateOfReturn) || isNaN(years)) {
            throw new Error("All inputs must be valid numbers.");
        }

        if (presentValue < 0 || rateOfReturn < 0 || years < 0) {
            throw new Error("Inputs must be non-negative.");
        }

        const futureValue = calculateFutureValue(presentValue, rateOfReturn, years);
        alert(`Future Value: $${futureValue.toFixed(2)}`);
    } catch (error) {
        alert(error.message);
    }
});

Specific Problem:
How can I improve the input validation and error handling to make it more robust and user-friendly? For example:
Is there a better way to handle validation at both the form and function levels?
Are there any best practices for handling missing or invalid data in calculations like this?
I would appreciate any feedback on improving the robustness of the calculator while keeping the code maintainable and user-friendly.

I think you can skip the things already validated by modern browsers since they handle it pretty well. For the extra things that HTML form validation can't manage, you should handle them separately. You can use HTMLObjectElement.setCustomValidity() to display custom error messages.
